# requests module doesn't recognise get attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

I received this error on pycharm about attribute get not being recognized by module requests

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


def get_quote():
    response = requests.get('https://api.kanye.rest')
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    quote = data["quote"]
    canvas.itemconfig(quote_text, text=quote)


window = Tk()

window.title("Kanye Says...")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)
canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=414)
background_img = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
canvas.create_image(150, 207, image=background_img)
quote_text = canvas.create_text(150, 207, text="Kanye Quote Goes HERE", width=250, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"),fill="white")


canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

kanye_img = PhotoImage(file="kanye.png")
kanye_button = Button(image=kanye_img, highlightthickness=0.1, command=get_quote)
kanye_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

this shows an error `AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'`, but requests has an attribute named get.

Comment: Please, post the full traceback verbatim. Most likely you have a module named `requests` that shadows `requests` package

Comment: It worked for me. I pressed the button to continue. You can see msg "quote":"I hear people say this person is cool and this person is not cool. People are cool. Man has never invented anything as awesome as a an actual person but sometimes we value the objects we create over life itself"

Comment: Do you have a file named `requests.py` where python might find it? What does `print(requests.__file__)` display?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have file named `requests.py` in your working folder. It imports it firstly (not the python `requests` library you need) and tries to use `get` attribute which it doesn't have.